# Using weak references in a static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to build a static library which support a deployment target iOS 4.3 and above.

The problem is that my code uses weak references.

Is it anyway possible to only build the library which uses weak references?

Answer (score 1):

There's [this library](https://github.com/plausiblelabs/PLWeakCompatibility) from Plausible Labs that makes this work.

> `PLWeakCompatibility` is a set of stubs that implement the Objective-C
>   runtime functions the compiler uses to make `__weak` work. It
>   automatically calls through to the real runtime functions if they're
>   present (i.e. your app is running on iOS5+ or Mac OS X 10.7+) and uses
>   its own implementation if they're not.